# Why Pointers To Functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'd like to ask that why and when do we need to use pointers to functions ? I did some searching and the answers I got were that so that we can use different functions at different times but we can still do that by directly calling the function instead right ?

Thank you.

Comment: There are lots and lots of use cases for (member) function pointers in c++. For many techniques these are essential. Your question is way too broad!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: isn't an answer at the same level of abstraction OK? and then, isn't the question OK? because otherwise, what abstraction level should we put as criterion for questions?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hmm, in some way you're right what can be answered how (that's why I upvoted your answer). Though this doesn't convince me that this is a good question in the actual form.

Comment: A specific example: Consider a system that receives and processes command messages, expressed in binary. Suppose there are 2000 distinct types of commands. The first two bytes of the message specifies the type of the command while the remainder of the message specifies the contents of the command. (Rhetorical question): What's better, a switch statement with 2000 cases (plus default) where each case calls the "right" function, or a simple command-to-function hash table that maps a command type specifier to a function pointer that processes that specific command type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function pointers provide a limited kind of polymorphism where you can call a function without knowing exactly which function it is.

I don't think there's any other way to do that in C.

In C++ it's possible to achieve about the same effect by using an object with a virtual member function, said object accessed through a base class reference or pointer. Then a direct use of an object pointer is serving much of the same purpose as that of the C function pointer.

However you can't do that when some software, such as a C library, *requires* a function pointer.

And often a function pointer is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}

int multiply(int a,int b){
    return a*b;
}

int calculate(int a, int (*fptr)(int,int),int b){
    return fptr(a,b);
}

int main(){
    int a=3,b=5;
    char ch;
    switch(ch=getch()){
         case 'a':
             cout<<calculate(a,add,b);
             break;
         case 'b':
             cout<<calculate(a,multiply,b);
             break;
    }
}
```